# How to set an event handler in a Django form input field

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms

How to set a JavaScript function as handler in the event onclick in a given field of a Django Form. Is this possible?

Any clue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for automating this process, you can create a custom widget for the field. In the widget class you will define a render method in such a way that it will also return the event binding code.

```
class CustomWidget(forms.TextInput):

    class Media:
        #js here
        js = ('js/my_js.js',)

    def render(self, name, value, attrs = None)
         output = super(CustomWidget, self).render(name, value, attrs)
         #do what you want to do here
         output += ...
         return output
```

Answer (score 24):

What I do for that is :

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    stuff = forms.ChoiceField(
        [('a','A'),('b','B')],
        widget = forms.Select(attrs = {
            'onclick' : "alert('foo !');",
            }
        )
```

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend looking at using a JavaScript library such as jQuery.  [Here](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/click#fn) is the link to binding the click event in jQuery.  Since Django names all of the input fields you can connect `my_field_name` in your Django form to the click event like so:

```
$("form input[name='my_field_name']").click(function () { 
    // Handle the click event here
});
```

Comment: I don't really see how there is a relation to Django

Comment: Fair enough. The only relation to Django here is how Django names the input fields based on the names used in the declarative form to get the binding correct. Overall this isn't really a Django question. It's a JS question.

Comment: It's a Django question on how to add the JS-events and this guy here answered it nicely: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1879919/2516892

Answer (score 2):

The Ghislain Leveque answer works to me, but in django 1.9 I did it like this:

```
class myForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = USER
        fields = ["password", "idCity"]
        widgets = {
            "password": forms.PasswordInput(),
            "idCity": forms.Select(attrs={'onchange': "alert('foo !');"})
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [YUI](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/), you can do that like this:

```
YAHOO.util.Event.addListener(id_myField, "click", myClickEventHandler, myOptionalData);
```

See also [YUI 2: Event Utility](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/event/)

I prefer using a JavaScript library, as this keeps browser-side JS code nicely separated from server-side Django.

Answer (score 0):

I took JQuery approach using Ghislain Leveque's answer. This way I was able to trigger the event handler on page load.

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    stuff = forms.ChoiceField(
        [('a','A'),('b','B')],
        widget = forms.Select(attrs = {
            'widget_to_bind' : "True",
            }
        )
```

In my javascript:

```
function myFunction() {
    var source = $(this); // Widget element
}

$('[widget_to_bind=True]').change(myFunction);
$('[widget_to_bind=True]').trigger("change");
```

Answer (score 0):

Variation on a theme:

```
class CategoriesForm(forms.Form):
stuff = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
    choices=([(pt.id, pt.name) for pt in PaymentType.objects.order_by('name')]),
    widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'size': '20', 'class': 'mc_payment_type'})
    )
```

JQuery:

```
<script language="javascript">
    $('.mc_payment_type').change(function () {
        console.log('payment type selected: ' + $(this).find('option:selected').val());
</script>
```